# Changes in DataTable not seen from another form

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datatable, datagridview

I have a DataTable in my DataSet which is not bound to any table in the SQL Database since I need it only inside 2 forms. When I update it in Form1, it works just fine, the table is populated and I can see the data inside a DataGridView (here is the code I use for updating it):

```
Dim newProcesRow As DataRow = Me.SampleDataSet.Tables("TableSample").NewRow()
newProcesRow("Col1") = val1.ToString()
newProcesRow("Col2") = val2.ToString()
newProcesRow("Col3") = val3.ToString()
Me.Sample_DataSet.Tables("TableSample").Rows.Add(newProcesRow)
```

After doing this, the DataGridView in Form1 shows the entire table with no problems. After the user clicks a button, Form2 is shown, where there is a DataGridView as well with the same DataSource as the grid in the first form, the unbound table from the DataSet. I also tryed putting a MessageBox in Form2 to return the number of rows from the DataTable and the result was 0. 
Is there any way I could make Form2 see the rows in the DataTable without binding it to the database? (I don't want to do unnecessary changes to the DataBase...) Or are there any saves/changes/updates I am not doing to the DataTable? 
If there is anything else I should mention in order to make it easier to find a solution, tell me and I will add. Thanks in advance for any piece of advice, have a nice day! (:

Comment: You just need to share the this DataSet. Use the same instance on both forms but don't make it `Shared`. Pass the instance of `SampleDataSet` to the `Form2` when you create it's instance.

Comment: That was it, thank you very much, Tim Schmelter!